# Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles! When opening tab in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm, floating-action-button

I'm getting the following error when I open a new tab / window in iTerm:

```
Last login: Fri Aug 12 10:44:50 on ttys000

Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.
```

Top part of my `.zshrc` file:

```
export ZSH=/Users/leongaban/.oh-my-zsh
export TERM="xterm-256color"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/leongaban/bin/subl:/usr/local/bin/fab"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thoughts? Everything runs fine still I can use my aliases to get to different directories, use git commands etc etc...

Comment: Is there anything special with the profile you used to open the tab ?

Comment: @sel-fish I don't think so, I just posted a new screenshot, is there any other file you'd like to see?

Comment: your default profile, not 'General' tab, can you show the content of your 'Profiles' tab ?

Comment: @sel-fish added! Also added some stuff up top from my `zshrc` file.

Comment: it seems caused by something in your ```.zshrc``` file, is there anything related to ```fab```

Comment: I just figured it out, posting answer....

Comment: well done, congrats :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following in my .zshrc file

```
# Deploy
fab deploy_to_bulk
```

I needed to comment out `fab deploy_to_bulk`